# Django query is returning blank values

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I'm writing an app that should list all teams from a local sports league inside a select box from which users can choose their favourite, however when I open the app everything looks good except that the select field shows only blank options. I know it's querying the DB correctly because it shows all 18 options inside the select box but they all appear blank and I get no error whatsoever.

Here is my model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'team'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.team_id
```

my view:

```
@verified_email_required()
def crearcuenta(request):
    equipos = Team.objects.all()
    form = CuentaForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CuentaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cuenta = form.save(commit=False)
            cuenta.user = request.user
            cuenta.equipo_favorito = request.POST.get("equipo", "")
            cuenta.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
    context = ({
        "equipos": equipos,
        "form": form
    })
    return render(request, "teams/crearcuenta.html", context)
```

And lastly the html:

```
<div class="col-md-8 form-group mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                        <label for="Equipo" class="col-md-3 control-label mdl-textfield__label">Correo</label>
                        <div>
                            <select id="Equipo" name="equipo" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true">
                                <option>Seleccione uno</option>
                                {% for equipo in equipos %}
                                    <option value="{{ equipos.team_id }}">{{ equipos.city }} {{ equipos.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working with AngularJS?

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, you have

```
{% for equipo in equipos %}
```

Inside your loop, you want to access the attribute of an individual `equipo`, so you should have `{{ equipo.team_id }}` instead of `{{ equipos.team_id }}`.

```
{% for equipo in equipos %}
<option value="{{ equipo.team_id }}">{{ equipo.city }} {{ equipo.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Ideally, you would include `equipo` in your form, and let Django take care of rendering the form (e.g. `{{ form.equipo }}`). Then you wouldn't have to manually render or validate the field, which prevents errors.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, that was the problem!